# Laravel view don't update after adjusting date or time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am creating password expiration (90 days) in laravel, then I adjust my current date and put it to 90 days (when changing view its still updating), after test I back my current date and update some view but view is not updating anymore.
My Procedure:

> Step 1: Go to your laravel project
>
> Step 2: change computer time (ex: if 1/29/2018 now, change it to
>   7/29/2018)
>
> Step 3: edit your laravel project, check if your view is updating (if yes proceed to step 4 )
>
> Step 4: back your current date, then update your code in view again,
>   its not updating anymore

I am using IIS as my server, laravel 5.1, php 5.5.

I already try to use this.

> composer dump_autoload
>
> composer clear-cache
>
> php artisan clear-compiled
>
> php artisan config:clear
>
> php artisan cache:clear

I already try to clear browsing data.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel caches view files. If the last modified time of the view is greater than cache file it will remove the cache file and make a new one. When you set the 90 date after current time it made a new cache file with future timestamp. But you reverted it back, the last modified date of the cache file is greater than view's last modified. So it's not going to update the cache file. So run command `php artisan view:clear`  to delete the cached files